# Can I create the GUI in Swift and do all the processing in C and call it in Swift?

Tags: android, ios, c, xcode, swift

I have code implemented for NDK in Android and I want to port it to iOS. Can I do that with a minor changes to the C and just call that in swift?

Comment: Depends on how much is done in your NDK code.  Anything dealing with the OS or display won't port directly.  But any algorithms/data structures can.

Comment: Thank You Gabe. My main concern is implementing the algorithms only. Is there a tutorial on how I can do all UI implementation with Swift but the algorithm is run on C?